# Android foreground service doesn't react after some time

Tags: android, service

In my application I need a service to be running. Under this assumption I set service as foreground service. My problem is that e.g. after 24 hours or after longer time of service disuse, service doesn't react. I can see my service in Running services but broadcast receivers of service doesn't work, scheduled timer tasks doesn't invoke themselves and so on.

I will be grateful for any ideas what could be reason of this behavior.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I have come to the conclusion that it was probably the size of SERVICE. Service grown to 16 Mb and then the service stop react.

Answer (score 0):

Ser a alarm Mabger which will wake after some time like every 2hours and see if your service is running or not , if not it starts the service

```
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), GeneralConstants.MAIN_SERVICE_CHECKING_TIME, pendingIntent);


if (!isServiceIsRunning(context)) {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, MainServiceAlwaysActive.class));
            }
public static boolean isServiceIsRunning(Context context) {

        // Activity manager to refer the activity/process running in system
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Loop to search
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {

            // Basic matching
            if ("com.signals.service".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Service is still running, I didn't find out anything from ActivityManager

Comment: isservicerunning is the method which will return true if service is running you need to provide proper package name in place of this ["com.signals.service"]

Comment: I know but? isServiceIsRunning() == true. And he doesn't react.

Comment: !isServiceIsRunning(context) this method will return false if service id not running if(!isServiceIsRunning(context)) this way or else paste your code